# what is a "Tragic missed opportunity"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, idioms

What is "A tragic missed opportunity."?

Context:

*It (The fight between Russia Tsar and landowners) was a tragic missed opportunity. Had the Tsar had pulled this off, Russian history would have been very different and surely happier.*

Source: History of the world by Andrew Marr - Episode 7

Comment: That should be, "Had the Tsar pulled this off ..." Only one "had", not two. I don't know if that error is in the original or if the poster made a mistake copying it.

Answer (score 2):

An "opportunity" is a chance to do something or accomplish something of value. Like if someone offers you a job, that's an opportunity.

A "missed opportunity" is a chance to do or accomplish something that you did not take advantage of. If someone offers you a job and you don't take it, that's a missed opportunity.

A "tragic missed opportunity" is a chance to do or accomplish something that you did not take advantage of, and missing it was a tragedy, that is, was a very bad thing. If someone offered you a very good job and you didn't take it, that could be a tragic missed opportunity.

So the writer is saying that the Tsar had a chance to do something good here: he had an opportunity. But he didn't do it, and the results of his not doing it were very bad, so it was a tragic missed opportunity.

Comment: Just a note to point out that “bad’ here in the sense of tragic is “very sad” not bad as in horrific or evil.